# How to route VPN traffic through two gateways?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables, home-networking

I would like to be able to establish a VPN tunnel from the internet to my OpenVPN server on address 192.168.1.45. My home network setup is a bit complex since I am using a Raspberry pi as a gateway to route all of the traffic on my home net through another VPN (called VPN 1 on the figure and represented by the thick line).

[Link to the schema of the network setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJW4t.png) (I cannot embed images yet apparently)

My setup works fine except that I cannot establish connections through VPN 2 in this configuration.

More config details: All gateways have fixed IPs. The LAN gateway is used by the VPN1 Gateway and forwards incoming traffic on port 8787 to port 1194 (rule set using my ISP GW GUI). Here are the iptables rules on the VPN 1 Gateway:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 15038 packets, 1421K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 1246 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 344 packets, 25041 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 183 packets, 13486 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
3     9959 1007K MASQUERADE  all  --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere
```

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 3111 packets, 248K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
2        8   688 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere
3     3507  233K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
5     193K  202M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 16 packets, 1408 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   eth0    anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   eth0    anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
5    97203   12M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun0    anywhere             anywhere
6     190K  190M ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth0    anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 104K packets, 18M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I tried adding rules like:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.45:1194
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.45 --dport 1194 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.43

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:1194
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --sport 1194 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.45

sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

but it didn't work. I'm now stuck and wasn't able to find a solution online... I'm also quite a noob in this domain unfortunately, I've been doing this for fun and have learned only by trial and error.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! I finally managed to route the packets the way I intended to. The solution was that iptables alone was not sufficient, I also needed to modify the routing of my VPN packets and add a new rule using the `ip` command.

Here's how I managed it if someone wants to do something similar:

```
# do port forwarding to the VPN 2 server and allow forward traffic
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.45:1194
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

```
# mark all packets that have to be routed through the 192.168.1.1 gateway
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 1194 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

```
# define desired specific route for marked packets
echo 201 openvpn1194.out | tee --append /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 1 table openvpn1194.out
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table openvpn1194.out
```

Note that you those changes will not persist after a reboot and you'd need to make them permanent if they do suit you.